# Why is String Interpolation Failing in erb Template?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, string-interpolation

I have the following code in a .erb file:

```
<% embed='<a href="http://someurl.com/whatever">#{@webcast.name}</a>'%>

<p id="embedCode">
    <pre>
        <code>
            <%= embed %>
        </code>
    </pre>
</p>
```

The anchor tag is correctly displayed onscreen as text rather than rendered as a dom element, however the string interpolation is failing. The html is successfully displayed as text but #{@webcast.name} is not evaluated. If a include <%= @webcast.name => in the template, the webcast name in rendered successfully.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because strings delimited with single quotation marks `''` are not interpolated.

Change your code to e.g.:

```
<% embed = "<a href=\"http://someurl.com/whatever\">#{@webcast.name}</a>" %>
```

or (if you want to avoid masking the double-quote  characters `"`)

```
<% embed = %(<a href="http://someurl.com/whatever">#{@webcast.name}</a>) %>
```

or just (thanks to [Samy Dindane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604041/samy-dindane) for the hint):

```
<% embed = "<a href='http://someurl.com/whatever'>#{@webcast.name}</a>" %>
```

Comment: You can use `'` as the `href` delimiter. I find this prettier. :)